# Where do packages downloaded via MDM installation get stored?

Tags: mdm, configuration-profiles

Trying to debug an MDM installation issue where a package gets downloaded, but during install, it complains about the following:

```
PackageKit: Install rejected with error: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=100 "Authorization is required to install the packages." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Authorization is required to install the packages.}
```

I am going to try to install the package manually with debug options, but I don't know where the package is downloaded.

Is there a standard file system location for them?

Comment: Refer to the documentation for whatever MDM solution you are using.  Re installing it with debug options... the error message seems pretty explicit.

Comment: I am not the MDM admin .. trying to debug it on my end.